# Codeigniter - rename controller 301 redirect old url's

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, seo

I had to rename one of my controllers as per my lawyer's recommendation and need to keep SEO and Google in mind when doing it - I still need all of the old URL's to work and/or use `301` redirects.

Redirect hint:

- `301` = Permanent
- `302` = Temporary

I know there are ways to do this using the `.htaccess` file but I'm not familiar with how it works and don't want to break anything.

Here are some resources on that if that's what you're looking for:

- [redirecting-old-dynamic-pages-to-new-one-with-friendly-urls-codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308710/redirecting-old-dynamic-pages-to-new-one-with-friendly-urls-codeigniter)
- [Codeigniter htaccess 301](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380233/codeigniter-htaccess-301)
- [301 redirect for old pages of the website with codeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284259/301-redirect-for-old-pages-of-the-website-with-codeigniter)

Comment: hi - just keep in mind that you can also use routes - so then you don't have to change your controller names / files / etc. Like if your controller was 'surly' with a 'grumpy' method - you can change the link to 'friendly' without changing the controller name $route['friendly/happy'] = "surly/grumpy";

Comment: Will that change the URL - because of legal reasons I can't use my old one.

Comment: you can use a different URL - and still have the same controller name. and you can even take the old URL - which normally would go to your controller - and have it go somewhere else. routes are cool! :-) so if the url was website.com/surly/grumpy you can create a route like  $route['surly/grumpy'] = "pleasedonot/sue/wearenicenow"

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest, SEO friendly, solution I could come up with that didn't include editing the `.htaccess` file:

```
<?php

class Old_controller extends MY_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        redirect(str_replace('old_controller', 'new_controller', "http://{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}{$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}"), 'location', 301);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Cheers!